# How do i change my code to start my SetTimeout at the same time?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

How do I change my code to start Blinking at the same time, and still be infinite?

function blink() {
    if (!toggleSwitch) {

```
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        shapes.push(elements[i].className);

    }
    // Start off at the first element.
    let i = 0;
    let len = shapes.length;

    // Do the next link
    function doNext() {

        let element = shapes[i];
        i++;

        eval(element).fillColor = eval(element).setColor;
        document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundColor = (eval(element).fillColor===document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundColor) ? 'white' : eval(element).setColor ;

        if (i < len) {
            // Don't do anything special
        }  else {
            // Reset the counter
            i = 0;
        }
        myVar = setTimeout(doNext, 1000);      }

    // And the code needs kicked off somewhere
    doNext();
}
```

}
Also I can't toggle Classes because with a drag and drop I can change the background color any time during a running time so I have an object for each shape where I keep what color is the background. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `setInterval`. See below for a basic functional blinking example.

```js
let red = true;
let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
  
setInterval(() => {
  red = !red;
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    if (red) squares[i].className = 'square red';
      else squares[i].className = 'square';
  }
}, 2000);
```

```css
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.red {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="square red"></div>
<div class="square red"></div>
<div class="square red"></div>
<div class="square red"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I can't toggle Classes because with a drag and drop I can change the background color any time during a running time so I have an object for each shape where I keep what color is the background.